# Why thread_local in different compiler or different platform has the different outcome?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local-storage

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

// not POD
struct A {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m_test;
};
struct B{
    thread_local static A a;
};

thread_local A B::a = A();

B b;

void func(){
    b.a.m_test[0]++;
}
int main() {
    
    vector<thread> Threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Threads.push_back(thread(func));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Threads[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code snippet is showed as above.
I built the same code in **Linux: gcc 4.8.5** and **MacOS:clang13.1.6** , outcome is the different  . In Linux, An error occurred as `17703 Floating point exception(core dumped)`, but in MacOS there was no error occurred.

---

I know thread_local can use in POD type after c++11, but here I use the unordered_map in struct, which internal memory is in the heap, not in the static or global storage area. So I wonder if this is because of how different compilers implement the C++ standard?
And how can I solve this runtime error on the linux platform?

Comment: probably it's a bug of old gcc. a newer one works with no issues https://godbolt.org/z/Y5a7oqhW4

Comment: gcc 4.8.5 is rather ancient (7 years).

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an old compiler? `thread_local` was only introduced in 4.8 so i wouldn't be surprised if it is buggy

Comment: If you are running on an HPC machine please use `module` commands to use a newer version of GCC. Default GCC are not meant to be used by end-users (it is kept only for sake of "stability" though admins are a bit too much conservative). If module is not available then please use packages like Spack. Singularity can also be used on some machine (quite rare). If you are on desktop then please install a newer version (it is completely obsolete for desktop machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on testing on compiler explorer, this seems to be a GCC bug fixed in 2019 for versions 9+, 8.4+ and 7.5+. The code should work fine as posted. There is nothing wrong with it.

Probably it is [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60702).

I recommend you install and use a more up-to-date version of GCC.